# make page size fit to contains?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a master page which contains dynamic menu items, how do I make the page size fit when I expand the header item in the menu?
This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="divHader" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul id="uiSideMenu" class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="/Default.aspx"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i>Home</a>

            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HeaderMenuId")%>' Visible="false" ></asp:Label>
                    <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse"  onclick ="full_screen()" data-target='#<%# Eval("HeaderMenuId")%> '><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows-v"></i> <%# Eval("HeadItemText")%>  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <ul id='<%# Eval("HeaderMenuId")%>' class="collapse">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li  >
                                    <asp:Label ID="PID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tblMenuItemID")%>' Visible="false" ></asp:Label>
                                    <a href="<%# Eval("MenuItemLink")%>"><%# Eval("MenuItemName")%></a>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </ul>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:Repeater>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using the JavaScript To keep its size = menu size + header size :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$(window).bind("load resize", function () {
    //alert($("divHader").height());
    topOffset = $("#divHader").height() + $("Footer").height();
    width = (this.window.innerWidth > 0) ? this.window.innerWidth : this.screen.width;
    if (width < 768) {
        $('div.navbar-collapse').addClass('collapse')
        //topOffset = 100; // 2-row-menu
    } else {
        $('div.navbar-collapse').removeClass('collapse')
    }

    height = (this.window.innerHeight > 0) ? this.window.innerHeight : this.screen.height;
    height = height - topOffset;
    if (height < 1)
        height = 1;
    if (height > topOffset) {
        $("#page-wrapper").css("min-height", (height) + "px");
    }

    if (height < $("#uiSideMenu").height()) {

        $("#page-wrapper").css("min-height", ($("#uiSideMenu").height()) + "px");

        //alert($("#page-wrapper").height());
    }

    if (height > topOffset) {
        $("#uiSideMenu").css("top", ($("#divHader").height()) + "px");
    }

});

});

function showHeight(element, height) {
    $("div").text("The height for the " + element + " is " + height + "px.");
}
$("#getp").click(function () {
    showHeight("paragraph", $("#divHader").height());
});
```

but it doesn't work!

Comment: When and how do you trigger full_screen function?

Comment: when expand items by clicking header in menu (menu have some headers each header have child's )

Comment: in some browsers **resizeTo** is only applicable on popup windows not main window. Would you please say more details what you mean from fitting page size (fit to what?)

Comment: some menu item appear under page (no scroll found to access this items )@ Ali Sheikhapour

Comment: screen.width and scree.height are your physical monitor dimensions and fitting window to screen make no sense! You have to set your **window height** to **document height**. However window has overflow:auto by default that make window to have scroll when content overflows. You probably set the overflow:hidden somewhere that cause the scroll to be hidden.